# 'IndexError: list index out of range' - reading & writing from same csv file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I have a created a program that **reads** data from a csv file and displays the data in listboxes, however the program also **writes** to a csv file. Originally I had separate files for reading and writing data but now I want to use the same file, however it throws up a 'IndexError: list index out of range'. I'm not sure why it is doing this when the program works perfectly when using two csv files.

for example I open, read and display results:

```
with open('QWERTY.csv', 'rt')as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    people=[]
    for column in reader:
        people.append(column[0:8])
    namesList = [x[0] for x in people]
    for names in (namesList):
        namebox.insert(END, names)
```

Then further on in the program I write to the same file:

```
with open('QWERTY.csv', 'a') as f:
    fieldnames=['name']
    writer=csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow({'name':i_name})
```

Comment: Might be helpful if you copuld share some lines of code ...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How in the world do you expect anyone to help you if you don't show us your code? We're not mind-readers.

Comment: "index out of range" means exactly what it says. All you have to do is do a bit of basic debugging to see what the index is, compared to what you assume it is, and what the contents of the indexed item is compared to what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem in the future, the solution is to remove the extra line.

```
writer=csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
```

Although it can be read with the extra line spacing by changing

This:

```
namesList = [x[0] for x in people]
```

To this:

```
namesList = [x[0:1] for x in people]
```

(in my example) blank results are shown so removing the extra line is a better solution.